# Finding rows with same values and further filter the result

Tags: sql

Given the following table and data

```
Create Table Employees(
  Employee_ID INT,
  PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50)
  );

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (1,'111'),(2,'111'),(3,'123'),(4, '123'), (5, '124'), (6, '124')
```

I want to return the duplicated phone numbers for employee with id 1.
I am able to get all the duplicated phone numbers for each employee using the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE PhoneNumber IN (
    SELECT PhoneNumber
    FROM Employees
    GROUP BY PhoneNumber
    HAVING COUNT(Employee_ID) > 1
    )
```

but I want to filter the result set using employee id as criteria.

Comment: Which database management system are you using

Comment: What do you mean you want to use employee id as a criteria?  Do you want to provide an employee id and get the employees that have a phone number matching the phone of the employee whose id is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
     JOIN Employees as Emp2 on Employees.PhoneNumber = Emp2.PhoneNumber
                       and Emp2.Employee_ID = @SearchForThis
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE PhoneNumber IN (
    SELECT PhoneNumber
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Employee_ID = @SearchForThis
)
```

Either of this would give you all the employee information for the employees having the same phone number as the phone number whose employee id you provide.

Comment: Could you please confirm this two queries are returning the proper duplicate record sets ?

Comment: @Mastero, is that a question to me? Yes, I tested the queries - they both work as expected.

Comment: @kouros . . . In that case, what you expect and what  you describe in the question are two different things.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, do you suggest that the two queries above might return different results or the description of my question is not that really precise?

Comment: @kouros . . . I see.  I figured you wanted to return rows *only* when the phone number is shared -- perhaps because you phrase the question in terms of duplicates.  This will return rows even when the phone number is unique.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - He **is** looking for duplicates, but also wanting to query by EmployeeID.  It wasn't entirely clear in his posting, but the thing that made most sense is that he is probably wanting to query to see people with the same phone number as a given employee.  I can see uses for such a query, including and not including the given employee.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, in your case the table schema don't have the Primary / Unique Key. So, Rank is the best solution. Kindly give the value for `@EmployeeId` in the following query.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER(PARTITION BY PhoneNumber
                ORDER BY PhoneNumber ASC) AS RN
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Employee_ID = @EmployeeId
)
SELECT Employee_ID, PhoneNumber FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1;
```

For more details refer this blog [Possible ways to remove Duplicate Records in a Database Table – SQL Server](http://www.increvcorp.com/possible-ways-to-remove-duplicate-records-in-a-database-table-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification to your query suffices:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
WHERE e.PhoneNumber IN (SELECT e2.PhoneNumber
                        FROM Employees e2
                        GROUP BY e2.PhoneNumber
                        HAVING COUNT(e2.Employee_ID) > 1
                       ) AND
      e.Employee_ID = 1;
```

However, a better way to write the query is:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employees e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Employees e2
              WHERE e2.PhoneNumber = e.PhoneNumber AND
                    e2.EmployeeId <> e.EmployeeId
             ) AND
      e.EmployeeId = 1;
```